# Вычисление параметров негативного биномиального распределения в R, используя метод максимального правдободобия

Tags: r, статистика

У меня есть датафрейм такого вида:

```
                             word freq1 freq2 freq3 freq4 freq5 freq6 
                          1   a    141   97    103   158   71    101
                          2   b    84    41    51    42    19    22
                          3   c    15    24    33    87    102   59
                          4   d    9     33    41    19    93    75
                          5   e    1     0     4     15    21    16
                          6   f    91    31    42    16    75    9
```

Предполагается, что данные действительно имеют негативно биномиальное распределение.
Я хочу найти параметры (r,p) негативного биномиального распределения, используя метод максимального правдоподобия в R для каждой буквы из датафрейма. Мне предлагали использовать метод mle2, но я так и не разобрался, что ему передавать в качестве параметров.

Например,  `word_a <- c(141,97,103,158,71,101)`
Как мне вычислить параметры НБР этого вектора?

Answer (score 0):

Если задача сводится именно к подбору параметров заранее известного распределения, то можно воспользоваться пакетом `fitdistrplus`:

```
word_a <- c(141,97,103,158,71,101)
fitdistrplus::fitdist(word_a, distr = "nbinom")
#> Fitting of the distribution ' nbinom ' by maximum likelihood 
#> Parameters:
#>       estimate Std. Error
#> size  17.20495   11.38275
#> mu   111.83002   11.82275
```